# Bootstrap page with 2 headers - lower is navbar-fixed-top - Content overlays top header when scrolling down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

For my C# asp.net mvc Razor _layout page I've not been able to find a solution for implementing a 2 row Header/Navbar for a Bootstrap page 
using navbar-fixed-top

My design calls for

• a simple 1 row feature at the top with hyperlinks to contact info and links to social media.

and below

• A standard bootstrap navbar

Here is a screen shot illustrating what I need to implement ( from the template that I purchased to build the site ) –

[example without fixed-top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya7Sb.jpg)

The 2 row menu in that implementation has no navbar-fixed-top class in either row.

When I run my version – with class="navbar-fixed-top " on the lower row -- (the standard Bootstrap navbar)

When scrolling down -- the body of the page is hidden by the lower navbar but shows on top of the top level header

Secondly

The top navbar does not behave responsively

The bottom menu works properly on small/xsmall

But

the social media icons to not wrap ... only the leftmost ( phone email links ) appear at top when displaying on a phone -- even tho that top row is configured as a set of two xs-small-12 columns

(The standard Bootstrap navbar below works perfectly (

I believe that my code is in line with standard Bootstrap conventions … but I am not reporting this as a bug … /thinking that this design is unsupported functionality.

Is there a workaround using some scripting code ?

I'm looking for an answer that shows a best practice to:

• Keep the body from appearing over the top header when scrolling

• Make the top header truly responsive and stack the 2 sides of that top header above each othw=er when the page falls into the sm-xs size ??

Thinking about and Angular or jQuery function that injects the top menu above the standard navbar after the page is loaded -- and repeat that process if browser is resized

All suggestions appreciated. Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work !!   Hope some of you find this useful .... so many top sites with complex ( and simple ) nav bars that scroll out of the page .... not a very good user experience IMHO

***navbar-fixed-top class is property of section that wraps the both rows (1) top row with links and (2) the navbar***

(Also needed to make some CSS changes to margins and paddings ....

strangely the view that is injected to _Layout  spilled over the Container/Row sections of the divs containing the RenderBody() and hid the top of the renderred view behind the header .. needed to fix that with margin settings

=======  CONTAINER / ROW IS INJECTED INTO LAYOUT VIA  "RenderBody"=======

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

   ******Main Page Content Here******


    </div>
</div>
```

HERE'S THE FIX ...

```html
         
navbar-fixed-top class is property of section that wraps the top row with links and the navbar 

    <section id="NFTParent" class="navbar-fixed-top">
                    <header id="Header-1" class="header">
                        @*<nav class="navbar navbar-default role=navigation">*@
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 header-info-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> Phone: 888-925-1858</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Mail: <a href="mailto: info@avanttek.com"></a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <!-- /.list-inline -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.header-info-wrapper -->
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 social-link-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="social-links">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <!-- /.social-links -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.social-link-wrapper -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.row -->
                        </div>
                        @*</nav>*@
                        <!-- /.container -->
                    </header>
                    <!-- /.header-1 -->
                    @*<header id="header-2" class="header navbar-fixed-top">*@
                    <header id="header-2" class="header">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="container">
                                @*<div class="row">*@
                                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Avant<span>Tek</span></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0.666667px;">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Home Layout 1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Home Layout 2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Home Layout 3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Home Layout 4</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Home Layout 5</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                <!-- /.container -->
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <!-- /.navbar -->
                    </header>
                </section>
            </div>

                <div>
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>

===================  CONTAINER / ROW IS INJECTED INTO LAYOUT VIA RenderBody() ===========================

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
LORUM IPSUM ..... CONTENT EMBEDDED IN ROW COLUMNS
    </div>


</div>
```